Cyclic Picker in React native?
I'm goign crazy trying to find a picker that can be cyclic, e.g. if we have a time from 1-12, once it goes past 12 it goes back to 1. I've found logical ways to do it but they're all clunky, There is an android package with a isCyclic function (react-native-wheel-picker-android) but I'm trying to find one for IOS as well. Heres the code right now, I'm using WheelPicker:
<WheelPicker
    selectedIndex={startHoursIndex}
    options={startHoursOptions}
    onChange={(index) => setStartHoursIndex(index)}
    visibleRest={1}
    itemHeight={20}
    selectedIndicatorStyle={styles.hourIndicator}
/>

Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you
I tried making a custom circular array but it doesn't render effectively:
const handleChange = (itemIndex) => {
    const optionsLength = startHoursOptions.length;
    let adjustedIndex = itemIndex;

    if (itemIndex < 0) {
        adjustedIndex = optionsLength - 1; // Go to the end of the array
    } else if (itemIndex >= optionsLength) {
        adjustedIndex = 0; // Go to the start of the array
    }

    setStartHoursIndex(adjustedIndex);
};


Which library are you currently using?  There are a lot out there (I googled react native wheel picker).  Some of them claim to support the features you want.

The only one I've found with that claims is the one I mentioned, what other ones have you found?
